# I don't know how to make a simple command

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i make a code

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "lockdown",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        message.delete();

        if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("you cant use it")

    message.channel.overwritePermissions(message.channel.guild.defaultRole , {SEND_MESSAGES: false});

    }
};
```

So but, with what problem? I need make be like so that after I wrote !lockdown he closed the channel(I did this already), and after I write again !lockdown it opened a channel(I need it)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what your looking for?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const lockdown= (client, message, args) =>{
    message.delete();
    if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")){
        message.reply("you cant use it")
    }
    message.channel.overwritePermissions(message.channel.guild.defaultRole , 
    {SEND_MESSAGES: false});

}

module.exports = lockdown
```

Comment: uh, i forgot say, that it is V11 discord.js

i mean, i need mmmmmm, after 2nd usage this command, permission will {SEND_MESSAGES: true}

Comment: just like that https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/582325992412938246/734661886699765831/unknown.png